# Get a random object of a Wagtail page model but not the current one

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

So I have this template context processor:

```
from cases.models import CasePage

def random_case(request):
    case = CasePage.objects.live().order_by('?')
    return {'random_case': case}
```

And in the template I do this:

```
{% for entry in random_case %}
{% if request.get_full_path != entry.get_url %}
{% if forloop.first %}

<a  class="ajax-link project-next" href="{{ entry.get_url }}">
<div class="nav-project-title">{{ entry.title }}</div>
<div class="nav-title">next</div>     
</a>

{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this works but the problem is sometimes the object is the same as the page so nothing is displayed. It would be great if that one would be skipped in favour of the next entry. And it's also too much logic in the template for me. What would be the best way to move this logic into the context processor and make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `random_case` a method of `CasePage`, and filter out the case with an ID equal to `self`.

```
class CasePage(Page):
    # ...
    def random_case(self):
        return CasePage.objects.live().exclude(id=self.id).order_by('?').first()
```

You can then refer to this method within your template as `page.random_case` - bear in mind that a new random choice will be made on each call, so you probably want something like `{% with page.random_case as case %}`.